# re-size css boxes with window

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s next to each other.

When I view the page full-screen they are okay.

But when I re-size the window, right `div` goes on the left one. and looks messy.

.

-I don't want this boxes to go on each other when I re-size.

I tried to use `max-width;` `min-width;` for that but I couldn't make it work.

.

-I tried to change font sizes to smaller/bigger with the windows size. I tried like; `font-size: 70%;` also couldn't make it work.

CSS:

```
.leftbox {
    top: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2em;
    max-width: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(121, 183, 0, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(43, 141, 6, 0.85);
}

#rightbox {
    top: 15%;
    right: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(121, 183, 0, 0.9);
    padding: 40px;
    max-width: 500px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(43, 141, 6, 0.85);
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="leftbox">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="rightbox">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6mttf9q/

Comment: When an element has been assigned `position: absolute;`, they will detach from the natural flow of elements and be unaware of the location or existence of other elements in their vicinity. Thus no way to achieve this using absolute positioning.

Can you explain why you chose for this approach; why would you need to position them absolutely?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: This is bad news. I did this because at their actual page, this `div`s front of the some video header. That's why I had to place this divs `absolute;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @JiFus method, but there is one more option for you, you can write Media Queries and overwrite

```
position: absolute;
```

by

```
position: relative;
```

for smaller screen or devices.

for example you may use this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.leftbox { position: relative !important; }
#rightbox { position: relative !important; }
}
```

here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/p6mttf9q/4/

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think best way is using this solution and @JiFus' solution together.

Comment: Oh, my Dear God! @Lukasz, this is the very first time my answer is accepted since the day i joined this forum! Very Happy I am

Answer (score 1):

Check out this  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6mttf9q/1/)

It's the best you can achieve when using absolute elements.
The bit of code doing the trick is:

```
.leftbox {
  max-width: calc(50% - 28px);
}
```

and

```
#rightbox {
  max-width: calc(45% - 88px);
}
```

What I'm doing here is calculating the max-width for both div's because you don't want them to overlap. Thinking you want both of the containers to take approximately 50% this is what it's calculated for both boxes:

Left box: 50% - padding (10px on both sides) - box shadow (4px on both sides).

Right box: 50% - margin-right (5%) - padding (40px on both sides) - box shadow (4px on both sides)

Comment: Thanks, It is works perfectly. I really get scared from `absolute` elements  though. I did them `absolute` because I wanted them to stay front of a video header. What would you suggest instead of `absolute` to make it work like that? I mean I want them _on_ html5 video.

Comment: `calc()` in CSS is the best invention since fire and the wheel! When in doubt, use `calc()`.

Comment: @Lukasz If you want an element to be on top of another one, specify the `z-index` here's a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)